# Java JTable specific row and column value + another integer

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I tried adding up a specific JTable cell value (in this case at (y,2)) with a value of another integer.

The idea is that you add up the initial value in the cell (which you convert to integer) with the value from JTextField (which you convert to integer)

```
int value = Integer.parseInt(table.getModel().getValueAt(y, 2)) + Integer.parseInt(materialsquantities[x].getText());
```

This line throws a problem. I guess this has something to do with the type of the cell value which should be a string (?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JTable` could contain any type of objects (e.g. `String`, `Integers`, etc), so  `getValueAt` returns `Object`, not a `String`. You should either cast result of `getValueAt` to `String` (if the `JTable` contains only `String`s) or explicitly convert `Object` to `String`, i.e. use `toString()` method. In both cases you should remember about possible `null` values.

Comment: Thanks, it explains everything and toString() fixes the problem! I will accept the answer as soon as it lets me.